# Using Dart / Flutter, How do I add favorites inside a ListViewBuilder?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to allow a user to mark an item being built by a ListViewBuilder as a favorite. With my current code, when a user favorites one episode, all episodes are marked as favorite. I would like the user to be able to add each episode individually as a favorite and persist that favorite after a restart. I have the data saved to a firebase database but it seems like this should be handled in the app itself.

What is the best way to do this? Thanks!

Here is my current code:

```
class Epi {
  final String endTime;
  final String name;
  final String networkName;
  final String showName;
  final String startTime;

  Epi({this.endTime, this.name, this.networkName, this.showName, this.startTime});

  factory Epi.fromJson(Map<dynamic, dynamic> parsedJson) {
    DateTime endTimeCon = DateTime.parse(parsedJson['endTime']);
    String newEndTime = formatDate(endTimeCon, [yyyy, '/', mm, '/', dd, ' ', hh, ':', nn, ':', ss, ' ', am]);

    DateTime startTimeCon = DateTime.parse(parsedJson['startTime']);
    String newStartTime = formatDate(startTimeCon, [yyyy, '/', mm, '/', dd, ' ', hh, ':', nn, ':', ss, ' ', am]);

    return Epi(
      endTime: newEndTime,
      name: parsedJson['name'],
      networkName: parsedJson['networkName'],
      showName: parsedJson['showName'],
      startTime: newStartTime,
    );
  }
}
```

```
  bool _isFavorited = true;
  void _toggleFavorite() {
    setState(() {
      if (_isFavorited) {
        _isFavorited = false;
      } else {
        _isFavorited = true;
      }
    });
  }
```

```
body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(height: 5.0),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: elist.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        selectEpisode(index);
                      },
                      child: Card(
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                          ListTile(
                            title: Text(elist[index].name),
                            subtitle: Text(elist[index].startTime),
                            leading: IconButton(
                              icon: (_isFavorited ? Icon(Icons.favorite_border) : Icon(Icons.favorite)),
                              color: Colors.red[500],
                              onPressed: _toggleFavorite,
                            ),
                            trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios)
                          )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  }),
            ),
          ],
        )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my Congress Fahrplan App ([Github](https://github.com/benjaminSchilling33/congress_fahrplan)) I'm doing exactly what you want to achieve.

In [favorite_provider](https://github.com/benjaminSchilling33/congress_fahrplan/blob/master/lib/provider/favorite_provider.dart) I store the value in the object itself and add it to my [list of favorited objects](https://github.com/benjaminSchilling33/congress_fahrplan/blob/master/lib/model/favorited_talks.dart). Whenever an object is added to this list, the list is written to the disk as JSON with my [file_storage](https://github.com/benjaminSchilling33/congress_fahrplan/blob/master/lib/utilities/file_storage.dart) class.

When the app is restarted, the objects are fetched from a REST API. Then I match their IDs with the objects from the local JSON and set whether they are favorited or not to restore the favorite state.

Answer (score 0):

Making a favorite list of items basically differs based on the app design and you might as well develop your own logic for this purpose. Now, while what @benjaminschilling33 posted is true, you can also achieve this in a simple way.
What I would do is, add a boolean called isFavorite on the constructor like this:

```
 class Epi {
  final String endTime;
  final String name;
  final String networkName;
  final String showName;
  final String startTime;
  bool isFavorite;
}
//initialize the isFavorite to false cause no item in your list is is favorite at the beginning
Epi({this.endTime, this.name, this.networkName, this.showName, this.startTime, this.isFavorite=false});

//lets create a list _episode which contains all the movie for demonstration purpose
List<Epi> _episode = [Epi(initialized data)]; 
//create a getter for the list
List<Epi> get episode{
  return _episode.where((Epi episode) => episod.isFavorite).toList(); //this will return a list where the isFavorite is true
}

//You can then set your icon (in the list-tile) based on your isFavorite result
ListTile(
...
icon: Icons(elist[index].isFavorite?Icon(Icons.favorite):Icon(Icons.favorite_border);
)
//Then adjust the logic on your onPress
onPressed: (){
   setState((){
    elist[index].isFavorite=!elist[index].isFavorite //this will vary from true to false and vice versa when pressed
});
}
```

This is the simplest way to add list of items that is favorited by the user rather than building another list for the favorite section. What I wrote here is offline based test you can achieve and the key take away is the where property which is:

```
    List<Epi> episode=[some data]
    epsode.where((Epi episode)=>episode.isFavorite).toList();
```

You can use this method even after deploying your app to the cloud database by creating that attribute in your database based on the user's id.